Resolved: How Can I Debug WinForms Designer Mode? (Design Time)
I'm only a hobby programmer, so please excuse if I don't know anything that seems obvious to you guys. For a while I've been trying to change from .NET Framework to .NET8.0 but mostly require WinForms for my Desktop solutions (VB preferred but some C#).
In any new project, adding a Windows Form via Solution Explorer seems to work at first, but after selecting it there's instantly an error thrown and the Form's Design doesn't show.
The error message is:

Illegal Character in path"

The list of calls reads
bei System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
bei System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Init(String path, Boolean checkHost)
bei Microsoft.WinForms.Utilities.Shared.ShadowCacheFolder.d__5.MoveNext()

Since I haven't changed any paths in my Visual Studio settings or to the projects, so I'd like to find out which path exactly I would probably have to change. Could one of you please be so kind as to guide me in debugging the relevant VS process?
Thank you in advance,
Michael
What I already tried:
I uninstalled and re-installed several versions of Visual Studio Community (2017, 2019, 2022), as some MVP from Microsoft suggested. Added (and finally deleted again) "Switches" to the devenv.exe.config file as another user with the seemingly similar problem had suggested. All to no avail.
I also followed the suggestions given in another question here ("How to debug Winforms designer") and tried to debug devenv.exe whilst additionally setting a breakpoint in the Form1.Designer.cs. This results in a perfectly empty "Form2" shown, so it seems the answer targets a different problem.
EDIT: A possible hint for someone more experienced might be that in .NET Framework there's no problem with Winforms at all!

What would it take for someone to reproduce this problem from scratch?

This appears very much like.NET 6 Winforms Designer / Argument Exception: Illegal characters in path #6826 that required setting the AppContextSwitchOverride Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling to false to solve, but then caused another problem for the poster.

@Wyck I wish I knew – coz then I might be able to narrow downthe error source. There's some probability that it's not VS related, and I hoped finding out which exact path has an "illegal character" would help.

@TnTinMn Yeah, I've mentioned that in "what I tried". In my case adding the setting didn't help, so I haven't encountered other problems but removed the setting again.

If you create a new WinForms VB.NET project in VS 2022, targeting .NET 8, this simply shouldn't happen, especially if you've re-installed VS.
What I can say would certainly solve the problem is a clean install/refresh of your OS and the reason I suggest this is because it appears as though the source of the problem is external to VS, perhaps residing in the filesystem or registry.
If your focus is WinForms, may I ask why you need .NET 8 and why 4.8.1 isn't sufficient?

Hello Brett, thank you for your response. I agree that it shouldn't happen and that a fresh OS usually helps resolve a problem with one app – unfortulately at the cost of days lost for re-installing hundreds of other apps :-( I considered to, if there'd be no way to debug and find out the relevant path (having an 'illegal character' in it), to transfer my whole VS environment to another computer in order to exsclude registry etc.

Addition: The reason why 4.8.1 may not be sufficient is that I've started experimenting with new features (e.g. "Span(of T)") which speed up my apps significantly.
As a potential workaround I've tried to write a .NET8 library with extensions and link them in 4.8.1, but that's obviously invalid – the compiler complains. Despite having 'pimped up' my 4.8.1 with numerous NuGet packages already,  I don't seem to be able to make these more recent commands (2-3 years old though) available.

Addition 2: Another workaround seems possible. I can design a form in 4.8.1 and then copy the readily designed form (or the relevant parts of the designer code) into the .NET8 project. A bit clumsy but another hint that only the VS process that loads the designer is affected.

G'day Mick, I sincerely hope that you do find a solution.  This has been bugging me since I first read your post.  I would hate the idea of having to reinstall the OS to fix the issue and wish I could replicate the problem here with VS 2022.  I strongly suspect it's something in the registry, but surely any incorrect values would have been removed/overwritten with a VS reinstall.  Manually copying across a 4.8.1 solution to a .NET 8 one is a pain, but I guess if you're only working on one or two, it's not so bad.  If you do that, does the designer work?

Hi Brett, thank you very much for catching up again! Despite the viable workaround I've spent a few evenings reorganizing my computers and installed my VS environment to another machine. NET8 works just fine now. In response of your question: The designer still didn't work and also didn't open my readily designed (in 4.8.1) forms. Not a very big thing, though, as I just kept a 4.8.1 winforms project in the project folder until the form design(s) were done... Anyway, it's now "history" and I'll mark this thread as resolved. Thank you again for your help, all the best and have a nice weekend!

G'day Mick, you're welcome.  I guess we can chalk it up as something esoteric on the machine you were originally using.  The OCD in me would convince me that the machine's OS was now somehow compromised and needed a reinstall.  I wish I was joking.  I make embarrassingly frequent images of the OS install because of things mysteriously breaking in the past. I'm glad you managed to get up and running again.  Now it's my turn to post about an infuriating issue I'm having with .NET 8 & VS2022!  Enjoy our weekend.
P.S.  Someone at Microsoft needs to think about a 4.8.1 -> .NET 8/9 migration path
